# Objective-C: Making iVars @public or @synthesizing @properties for them? When should I use properties?

Tags: objective-c, properties, ivar

I have some instance variables in my class that I'd want to be accessible anywhere. Like so:

```
@interface SomeObject : NSObject
{
    @public
        NSString *someString;
}
@end

@implementation SomeObject
@end
```

I can access the property from the instance using the `->` syntax like below, as I would do in C++:

```
someObjectInstance->someString
```

Should I make a property for `someString` when all I want is for it to be accessible by the outside world? I would create a `@property` for `someString` in my interface and `@synthesize` it in my implementation, which would enable me to access it using the dot syntax.

Comment: See my answer to the similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555736/objective-c-why-do-we-declare-ivars-in-the-h-member-area-if-property-seems-to/19470096#19470096).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, if you want to expose data, you should use properties. Making instance variables public is a bad idea in general.

Comment: The real question is: why is it a bad idea?

Comment: Because it makes future changes to your class impossible... what if you want to remove the actual ivar, and just return some other values by hand-implemented accessor methods?

Comment: What if, in this particular case, I am fairly certain that I wouldn't want to hand-implement the accessor methods. Would it be correct to use public ivars in this case? This is more of a general object-oriented question than an objective-c specific question.

Comment: In addition, making a habit out of accessing through getters and setters exclusively is good practice, because it allows the implementing class to control access (for instance, count the number of times a certain value has been accessed).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because what you're doing when you make it a `@property` is directing folks using it to call the `setSomeString` and `someString` methods, in effect.  Even if you're `@synthesize`ing them, it's better for your code quality to be using the methods, because you *could* change them if you need to.  If you're just using the pointer reference, if you find yourself needing to intercept accesses you won't be able to.